# C++ Library distribution with a Main()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, static-libraries

#### Question

Is it ok for a C++ Library to have the auto-generated main() function, since the main() is not in the Header file that is distributed with it?

If it is not ok, then would it be better to wrap an #ifdef _DEBUG around main()?

#### Scenario

I have a C++ Visual Studio project that wraps all our message queue functionality to abstract whatever AMQP we are currently using, and it is compiled as a Library in the Release configuration.

In the Debug Configuration, it is compiled as an executable so that some tests can be ran on it to confirm that it is working.

I have been looking around all morning and can't find any references to what is considered best-practice in this regard.

The idea is that the only part of the library that is used is the put() and get() from the MessageQueue class that is in the library.

Comment: In general, I would say 'Yes'. The framework googletest(for unit tests) ships a library 'gtest_main' which contains a main(). The purpose is to write some tests and link it with the lib containing the generic main() function.

Comment: You are aware, that you are not testing the library if you make it an executable !?

Comment: You could always create a dummy project that uses your library, if it's for testing sake

Comment: @DieterLücking For the sake of this question, lets assume that I am aware.

Comment: Hence it is OK. You can consider a debug and release build as two distinct 'projects'.

Comment: @KABoissonneault That would work, but would creating a separate project be considered best-practice? Because the original project still has the default "main()" which brings me back around to should I remove it, leave it in, or #ifdef it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just refactor the test piece and your problem goes away: Always build your code as a library with no `main` function at all and have a *totally separate project* that links to the library and does the tests. That way it's built in a way completely similar to actual release use rather than as a self-contained binary executable that's not the same set of circumstances as a normal release usage.